# JavaFX Button setFont

Tags: button, javafx, fonts

I am working on small JavaFX project. This time I want to change font of text shown on my buttons. I tried to do this like this:

```
Button button = new Button("Not formatted text");
Font font = new Font(40); //Button font's size should increase to 40
button.setFont(font);
```

but it simply doesn't work - size remains same as before. Also it looks like there is no simmilar method to achieve this.
How to change font of text on JavaFX button? I know that this question looks kind of trivial, but, seriously, I spent almost 1,5h looking for this and I am giving up. Please, help me :(

Comment: The shown code should work. Does the button have some custom style? Since the style is preferred the code `button.setStyle("-fx-font-size:10");button.setFont(new Font(40));` would set the font-size to 10.

Comment: Yes, you were right - I have a css file and didn't see that I have changed style, sorry.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

try

```
button.setStyle("-fx-font-size:40");
```